# The function calculates an age (how to do a reverse)

Tags: php, datetime

I need to do the opposite. To the input data was age and the output date of birth (year, month, day)

```
    function calc_age( $byear, $bmonth, $bday )
{
    $date = new DateTime("$byear-$bmonth-$bday");
    $now = new DateTime();
    $interval = $now->diff($date);
    echo $interval->y;
}
```

Comment: What you want to say...?

Comment: I need to do the opposite function

Comment: What criteria do you supply for age? Just years or years, months, days,hours etc?

Comment: input data just someone's age (35), output dada i need (year, month and day)

Comment: month and day must be "today"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
Example :

```
$age = 10;
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$age.' years'));
echo $date;  // Ex : 2007-11-25
```

Comment: Yeah, it's ok. I modified a bit.... $age = 10;
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$age.' years'));
    $d = explode("-", $date);
    echo $d[0],$d[1],$d[2];

Comment: That's fine. You can convert as you want.